# Jump values of N bits set?

Tags: c++, bit

I want the next + 100,000 value of a number with N bits, given that the resulting value must have N bits as well.

So, for example :
30 is `0b11110`

and the next value is
39 `0b100111`;

I read [that links](https://web.archive.org/web/20130731200134/http://hackersdelight.org/hdcodetxt/snoob.c.txt) and got a way to find the next value with N bits.

Now, is there a way to "jump" 100,000 values at once?

100,000 is arbitrary here, it could be -much- higher.

The only way I can think of is to make my jump from my initial value, count the number of bits of the new value and adjust that new value at the bit level to my desired N bits. That's a very manual process and I would like to know if a more efficient algorithm exists. But it gives me no guarantees on the number of values jumped.

Comment: Sometimes you need to think in a different direction, if you want to look for numbers with the same number of bits set think permutations e.g. : https://onlinegdb.com/KwiesXZKD. From there is should be easy to make a list of values and sort them.

Comment: @PepijnKramer: yes but it means calculating all the values, which I want to avoid, i want a jump

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expand on maxim1000's answer:
if `C(n,k)` is the number of n-bit values with k bits set, then `C` is just the [binomial coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient). It can be computed as `C(n,k) = C(n-1,k-1) * n / k`, with the limit being `C(n,0) = C(n,n) = 1` (and `0 <= k <= n`).

From there, you can compute a number's index by iterating through its bits from most significant to least significant (left to right). If the number has n bits total and k bits set, then, when encountering a bit set, the index is `C(bit_position, k) + subindex`, where `bit_position` is the bit's position (0 is the least significant, n-1 the most significant), and `subindex` is the index of the number if you unset that bit. Note that two numbers can have the same index if they have a different number of bits set.

For example, there are 10 5-bit numbers with 3 bits set. Here they are, along with their indices:

```
00111 - 0
01011 - 1
01101 - 2
01110 - 3
10011 - 4
10101 - 5
10110 - 6
11001 - 7
11010 - 8
11100 - 9
```

The index of `10110` is 6:
-- the first bit set is in position 4, with 3 bits set, so that's `C(4,3)`;
-- the second bit set is in position 2, with 2 bits set left, so `C(2,2)`;
-- the third bit set is in position 1, with 1 bit set left, so `C(1,1)`.
That makes `C(4,3) + C(2,2) + C(1,1) = 4 + 1 + 1 = 6`.

To go from an index to the corresponding number, you just need to do the reverse: start with a value of 0 and set each of the bits that correspond to a `C(p,k)`, where `k` is a known constant and `p` goes from `n-1` to `0`.

Then, to jump `j` values ahead, you can convert take the number's index, add `j` to it, and convert back to a number.

Here is an implementation:

```
auto binomial(uint64_t n, uint64_t k) -> uint64_t {
    if (k > n) {
        return 0;
    }
    if (k == 0 || k == n) {
        return 1;
    }

    // use the GCD to prevent overflow from `binomial(n-1, k-1) * n`
    uint64_t gcd = std::gcd(n, k);
    return binomial(n-1, k-1) / (k / gcd) * (n / gcd);

    // if you have access to a 128-bit type, you can also use that:
    // return binomial(n-1, k-1) * static_cast<__int128>(n) / k;
}

auto indexOf(uint64_t n, uint64_t bitCount) -> uint64_t {
    auto index = uint64_t(0);
    for (auto bit = 0; bit < 64; ++bit) {
        auto bitmask = uint64_t(1) << (63-bit);
        if ((n & bitmask) != 0) {
            index += binomial(63-bit, bitCount);
            --bitCount; // underflow doesn't matter here
        }
    }
    return index;
}

auto fromIndex(uint64_t index, uint64_t bitCount) -> uint64_t {
    auto n = uint64_t(0);
    for (auto bit = 0; bit < 64; ++bit) {
        auto b = binomial(63-bit, bitCount);
        if (b <= index) {
            auto bitmask = uint64_t(1) << (63-bit);
            n |= bitmask;
            index -= b;
            --bitCount; // underflow doesn't matter here
        }
    }
    return n;
}

auto bitCount(uint64_t n) -> unsigned int {
    auto count = 0u;
    while (n != 0) {
        if (n & 1 != 0) {
            ++count;
        }
        n >>= 1;
    }
    return count;
}

auto jumpOptimized(uint64_t n, uint64_t jumpLength) -> uint64_t {
    auto b = bitCount(n);
    auto index = indexOf(n, b);
    return fromIndex(index + jumpLength, b);
}
```

It can probably be optimized further, but hopefully this is written clearly enough to give you the idea.

Here is a naive implementation using `std::next_permutation`, to test against the optimized implementation:

```
auto jumpNaive(uint64_t n, uint64_t jumpLength) -> uint64_t {
    auto toBitVector = [](uint64_t n) -> std::vector<int> {
        auto v = std::vector<int>{};
        for (auto bit = 0; bit < 64; ++bit) {
            auto bitmask = uint64_t(1) << (63-bit);
            if ((n & bitmask) == 0) {
                v.push_back(0);
            } else {
                v.push_back(1);
            }
        }
        return v;
    };
    
    auto fromBitVector = [](std::vector<int> const& v) -> uint64_t {
        auto n = uint64_t(0);
        for (auto bit = 0; bit < 64; ++bit) {
            if (v[bit] == 1) {
                auto bitmask = uint64_t(1) << (63-bit);
                n |= bitmask;
            }
        }
        return n;
    };

    auto bitVector = toBitVector(n);
    for (auto i = uint64_t(0); i < jumpLength; ++i) {
        std::next_permutation(bitVector.begin(), bitVector.end());
    }
    return fromBitVector(bitVector);
}
```

And you can try both of them in [this complete demo](https://godbolt.org/z/3jjdGP684).

Comment: It's the answer I was looking for. I just tested and it works wonder. Thanks a lot

Comment: I converted your binomial function to c and compiled with gcc and it appears to overflow binomial(63, 30) = 860778005594247069, correct answer = 245886536470595348. If you replace the n with (__int128)n in the return expression it works for n up to and including 64. Maybe c++ works differently, but I thought you should know in case you need to update it.

Comment: @SimonGoater Good catch, though I think you mean 860778005594247069 is the correct answer. That's indeed because `binomial(n-1, k-1) * n` overflows (in C++ too). I've made a correction.

Comment: Oh yeah, cut and paste fail...

Comment: Nice answer! In C++20, consider using [`std::popcount`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/popcount) instead of `bitCount`.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Ah yes I forgot this function existed. But that's far from the only thing that can be optimized. Memoization for `binomial`, early out for `indexOf` and `fromIndex`... perhaps the indices can even be precomputed in some sort of table.

Comment: @Nelfeal: 10 months later, do you think there is a much faster way to decide the value at offset than what we have here ? We can't memoize that much data and for larger numbers, it becomes impractical very quickly <-> calculation time..

Answer (score 1):

We could try to index all values with N 1's in the order of their numeric values. After that we can calculate index of the starting number, add 100000 to it and then convert the index to a number again.

Let's call `f(M,N)` the number of M-bit values with N 1's (it's `N!/M!/(N-M)!`). If our number has 0 in the most significant bit, we can just consider it as (M-1)-bit value. If its MSB is 1, we can count numbers with N bits before `100...00` (which is `f(M-1,N)`) and add the count of numbers with N bits after `100...00` (which is the count of (M-1)-bit numbers with (N-1) 1's). This allows us to convert an N1's number to its index.

If I haven't missed anything, the conversion back is just reversing every step.

The complexity looks like `O(max-bit-count)`.

P.S. Sounds quite complicated, hopefully someone will find something simpler...

Comment: Yes that's a good start; so we manually set the bits, nothing is "automatic", but that's a good start